# How to apply a patch to indicator applet?

Tags: indicator, programming, patch

I have a patch named "incator.patch". How can I apply that to the application "indicator applet" and get it running? The bug will solve a bug with key-binding caused by "indicator applet".

Patch is here : launchpadlibrarian.net/52193166/hotkey.patch .

Comment: lol? This question needs a little *detail* in order for anyone to provide an answer. Is it an applet you created? One from another program? The entire indicator applet itself?

Comment: @Roland Taylor: I just switch to linux recently.Patch is here. It will solve a bug with key-binding caused by "indicator applet". http://launchpadlibrarian.net/52193166/hotkey.patch  .

Comment: I think you would need to report a bug on indicator-applet and ask the developers to take a look at your patch.

Comment: @Roland Taylor: It has already been reported and the patch fixed the bug in a brute way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quickly generate new packages with your patch applied, run the following in a gnome-terminal:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-applet
sudo apt-get install devscripts
apt-get source indicator-applet
cd indicator-applet-<version-string>
cp /path/to/patch/indicator.patch .
patch --dry-run -p1 < indicator.patch
```

Continue only if that succeeds without errors.

```
patch -p1 < indicator.patch
debuild -us -uc
```

Now wait for the thing to compile and if everything worked, you'll get some debs ready for install:

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i *.deb # I'm lazy, just choose the debs that are already installed
```

You'd need to do this **every time** the indicator-applet gets updated (but then I don't know how often such updates happen in stable releases).